# jQuery tweet plugin does not fetch tweets

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I am using a jquery tweet plugin. I am unable to figure out why the plugin is not fetching any tweets. I see that there are no js errors when I look at the firebug console.

http://www.montereytravelguide.com

The twitter widget in the footer uses the jquery tweet plugin.

I would appreciate any help

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your query to twitter returns an empty result :

```
http://twitter.com/status/user_timeline/montereytravel.json?count=3&callback=jQuery151031489942711777985_1304067889969&_=1304067890328
```

returns :

```
jQuery151031489942711777985_1304067889969([]);
```

First, It seems the correct url should be like :

```
http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=montereytravel
```

But it requires an authenticated user. I guess your plugin is outdated or misconfigured

Answer (score 0):

Have you included the reuired js file?
http://tweet.seaofclouds.com/jquery.tweet.js

Comment: the $.tweet function is defined in http://www.montereytravelguide.com/wp-content/w3tc/min/70b412/default.include-footer.2769256583.js So it's included

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use Mike Alsup's Twitter plugin instead?
View Demo: [jQuery Twitter Search Plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/twitter/)

Comment: Thanks. The plugin looks good. I think I will switch to this one.